# Hide previous div onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following page structure (super simplified):
I can have X (dynamic) number of idle-variables.

```
<div class="idle-variable">
<div class="var-container">content</div>
<a href="#">Save</a>
</div>
<div class="idle-variable">
<div class="var-container">content</div>
<a href="#">Save</a>
</div>
```

My Problem:
When I click save within the second instance of "idle-variable", I want to hide the "var-container" of the previous DIV set.  Again, there can be several idle-variable divs at any given time.  Anytime the save button is clicked, it should close/hide the "var-container" of the previous div set.

I've tried:

```
$(".var-container").hide()

$(".var-container").prev().hide();
```

But they are not working.  The first example closes/hides both and the second will close "idle-variable".

Any thoughts here?

Comment: When you say 'previous div set', do you mean the `.idle-variable` div that encloses the 'save' link that was clicked? Because the way you describe it makes it sound like you are talking about the previous `.idle-variable`.

Comment: I re-read this and decided to delete my upvoted post. It really isn't clear what is being asked. I don't think any of the answers (at the time I posted this comment) are corrected based on OP. It almost sounds like the save button should hide the content of the save button that comes before it (which doesn't make any sense to me).

Comment: @Jay When I click on the second save link, I want to hide the  var-container div within the first idle-variable div.  Basically what this is ultimately doing is when I start to interact with the second idle-variable div, i want the first one to be hidden, BUT only the var-container part.  Finally, because there can be 3, 4, 5 different idle-variable divs, on click of the save link, should always hide the var-container in the div set above it.

Comment: @Steve to simplify things, when I click on the second save instance, I'd like for something like this to happen `<div class="idle-variable"><div class="var-container" style="display: none;">content</div><a href="#">Save</a></div><div class="idle-variable"><div class="var-container">content</div><a href="#">Save</a></div>`.   (NOTICE the display none)

Comment: @user2828701 So you'd like the var-container to hide, but not the save link? If so, see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).prev().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the HTML:

```
<div class="idle-variable">
    <div class="var-container">content 1</div>
    <a href="#">Save</a>
</div>

<div class="idle-variable">
    <div class="var-container">content 2</div>
    <a href="#">Save</a>
</div>

<div class="idle-variable">
    <div class="var-container">content 3</div>
    <a href="#">Save</a>
</div>
```

You can hide `.var-container` div before the link using the jQuery code:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
    $(this).prev('.var-container').hide();
});
```

You can test this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WqvkG/2/).

Comment: you're just about there...any thoughts on if I click the save button under "content 2" it hides "content 1"?  Or if I click on save under content 3 it hides content 2?

Comment: You want it so that if you click the 'save' on content2, it will hide content 1?

Comment: thanks for sticking with me, Steve.  Your answer was very close and lead me to find the solution.  Perhaps I was not descriptive enough.  Ultimately I was looking for this:  `$(this).parent().prev().children(".var-container").hide(500);`

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to hide the entire .idle-variable, not just the .var-container. At any rate, I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the content div immediately before the save button when you click on it, use:

```
$('div.idle-variable a').click(function(){
    $(this).prev().hide();
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LK8my/)**